# no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to parse a line of JSON using ruby and running into this error

**no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)**

```
uri = URI.parse('xxx')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

if response.code == "200"
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)

  result.each do |doc|
    #if doc.is_a?(Hash)
      dns_name = doc['dns_name'] #reference properties like this  <-- Line 25 (see below)
      host = ['host']# this is the result in object form
      #end
  end
else
  puts "ERROR!!!"
end

puts host
puts dns_name
```

I have looked at several similar questions but they didn't seem to help and I have tried changing

```
      result.each do |doc|
```

to

```
      result.each.first do |doc|
```

as discussed in them.

My ruby is passable at best but I would take a link to some docs as well, I have tried the official docs without much luck at this point.  Here is what is returned:
           `[{"name":"server","power_state":"On","host":"host","cluster":"cluster","ip_address":"10.0.0.0","dns_name":"server.com","vcenter":"vcenter","description":" ","datastore":"datastore","num_vcpu":"2","mem_size_gb":8,"vmid":"1","application":"Misc","business_unit":"","category":"","support_contact":"joe@example.com"},200]`

I have also tried .is_a?(Hash) and .is_a?(Array).  I am fairly certain when I look at the json it is an array of hashes and the problem lies in the 200 response code I am getting back at the end of the line. Why that is a problem I have no idea, I would like to work around it but the json is generated by a known source so I may be able to have them modify it if I can show that it is faulty.

Thanks

### UPDATE

As asked the full out from the error

'./status.rb:25:in `[]''

'./status.rb:25:in `block in ''

'./status.rb:23:in `each''

'./status.rb:23:in `''

Comment: Give the full error stack trace to find it out quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it doesn't really seem like their is a reason for the loop, you could just write:

```
dns_name = result.first['dns_name']
host = result.first['host']
```

Since result is an array with 2 objects 0 being the Hash and 1 being an Int that should work.

Comment: For those reading this the above answer will work but the code should be `dns_name = result.first[dns_name']`.  There is no method ['dns_name'] but the new way of thinking about the problem was worth the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you well-format the JSON it will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"server",
        "power_state":"On",
        "host":"host",
        "cluster":"cluster",
        "ip_address":"10.0.0.0",
        "dns_name":"server.com",
        "vcenter":"vcenter",
        "description":" ",
        "datastore":"datastore",
        "num_vcpu":"2",
        "mem_size_gb":8,
        "vmid":"1",
        "application":"Misc",
        "business_unit":"",
        "category":"",
        "support_contact":"joe@example.com"
    },
    200
]
```

You want to access the hash, it's the first element in the array so:

```
if response.code == "200"
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    dns_name = result.first['dns_name']
    host = result.first['host']
else
  puts "ERROR!!!"
end
```

No need for an `each`.